# Can a sequence of functions diverge to infinity in one point and converge a finite limit in another?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Lets say $f_n:G\to \mathbb{R}$ diverges to $\infty$ in $a$. Does that mean that $(f_n)$ divergeres overall ?

Comment: Be sure you don't ask two different questions in the question's body and in the header...

Comment: This is very confusing, and since there are two conflicting answers, I think the question should be deleted and re-asked more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to the title: of course it can:

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n\text{ if }x=0\\0\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Of course not (answering to the body of the question). For example take

$$f_n(x):=x^n\;,\;\;\text{then}\;\;f_n(2)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\,,\,\,\text{yet}\;\;f_n(1)=1\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

Answer (score 0):

$f_n$ can also converge pointwise, for instance $f_n(x)=\dfrac{n}{1+|nx|}$ converges pointwise to $\dfrac 1{|x|}$.

$f_n(x_0)$ converges for all $x_0\neq 0$ but $f_n(0)=n$ diverges.